Symmetric power on ideal sheaf of submanifold of a singular complex space
Let  $X$ be a complex analytic space (possibly singular). Let $Y$ be a subvariety (reduced+irreducible)
of $X$ that is smooth.  We denote the ideal sheaf associated to $Y$ by $\mathscr{I}$.
Question:  Is the canonical morphism
$$S^{m}\left(\mathscr{I} / \mathscr{I}^2\right) \rightarrow \mathscr{I}^m / \mathscr{I}^{m+1}$$
isomorphic? (where $S^{m}$ is the $m$-th symmetric power and $m\in \mathbb{N^+}$ some positive integer)
Clues: Note that when $X$ is smooth, the morphism is indeed isomorphic. Moreover, in the case where $X$ is a complex analytic space and $Y$ is locally a complete intersection in $X$, the above morphism is also isomorphic.

No. For instance, take $X$ to be a quadratic cone and $Y$ to be its vertex.

Thank you. Could you provide further elaboration on the details? Specifically, in this instance, what is the calculation results of $S^m\left(\mathscr{I} / \mathscr{I}^2\right)$ and $\mathscr{I}^m / \mathscr{I}^{m+1}$? Alternatively, could you recommend some references for understanding this specific calculation?

In this example, the two spaces are the graded components of the two algebras: $k[x,y,z]$ and $k[x,y,z]/(f)$, where $f$ is the quadratic equation of the base of the cone.
